# in django 1.8, how to set sender for post_migrate and post_syncdb signal receiver when a custom user model is set?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals, django-1.8

Following is my code in the signals.py file placed in the package where the auth model is defined.

```
@receiver(post_migrate, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def define_groups(sender, **kwargs):
    # Create groups
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Promoter')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Client')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Superuser')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Staff')
```

The documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) states that it should be set as

```
sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

while this only works for post_save as mentioned in the documentation example.

I've already tried **get_user_model()** and also directly using the **my_custom_user.models**.

**get_user_model()** returns an error, while setting models as sender works just fine, as -

```
from . import models

@receiver(post_syncdb, sender=models)
def define_groups(sender, **kwargs):
    # Create groups
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Promoter')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Client')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Superuser')
    Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Staff')
```

But according to documentation this is not the right way to refer a custom user model and is just an ugly workaround.

Would someone please be able to help me with a solution so i can add these Groups with the first migration of user model.

Thank You

EDIT : using get_user_model() returns the following error -

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Comment: Hi @RA123, I'm trying to archive the this same issue, but my custom signal doesn't get fired. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sender` for the [`post_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-migrate) method is never a model (custom or otherwise), it is the `AppConfig` instance for the app which was installed.

The docs give the following example for connecting your signal handler in the `ready` method.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # Your specific logic here
    pass

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(my_callback, sender=self)
```

Similarly, the sender for `post_sync_db` signal (note the signal is deprecated) is the module containing the models which were installed.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for your answer, it worked perfectly and forgive me for my ignorance as i believed i could use the post_migrate like the other signals.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, I'm trying to archive the this same issue, but my custom signal doesn't get fired. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sgmart please ask a new question rather than adding a comment to an old question.

Comment: But I'm sure, my question is gonna be marked as duplicated.

Comment: @sgmart I doubt you are trying to use `post_syncdb` with a model, so it's not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Here's my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446788/defining-a-custom-post-migrate-signal, thanks in advance.